# Hi I want to read a parameter from a telegram table using telegram robot and send it to the user but my request fails

Tags: php, telegram, telegram-bot

This is my function to query

```
function getUser($user_id){
    global $db;
    $query="select * from users WHERE user_id='$user_id'";
    $res=mysqli_query($db, $query);
    $res=mysqli_fetch_assoc($res);
    file_get_contents($res);
    file_put_contents('result22.txt', $res.PHP_EOL,FILE_APPEND);
}
```

This my case to send it by a message

```
 case'information':{
                    $Stock=getUser($user_id)['Stock'];
                    $invited=getUser($user_id)['invited'];
                    $msg=urlencode("$invited\n\n$Stock");
                    send_message($user_id,$msg);
                    }
                        break;
```

The above causes the following exception:

> Blockquote
>     file_get_contentshttps://api.telegram.org/bot984745149:AAH_g_Zuo9T****SDlS6_W7aISlsRAuCWY/sendMessage?chat_id=129372728&text=%0A%0A: failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request
>    in /home/v/public_html/New/bot.php on line 63
>   PHP Warning:  file_get_contents() expects parameter 1 to be a valid path, array given in /home/v/public_html/New/bot.php on line 116
>    PHP Warning:  file_get_contents() expects parameter 1 to be a valid path, array given in /home/v/public_html/New/bot.php on line 116'

Functions in question:
[image: code example]
[image: code example 2]

Comment: _“Warning: file_get_contents() expects parameter 1 to be a valid path, array given”_ - what is unclear about that?

Comment: (That you would get both those errors at the same time, from the same call, makes no sense though.)

Comment: Check the output of: mysqli_fetch_assoc($res);  Function: file_get_contents() does not like the argument you're passing to it.

Comment: _“HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request”_ - then call that same URL in your browser, and see what result that gets you - there’s likely an error message in there.

Answer (score 0):

In your getUser function, you have:

```
    $res=mysqli_query($db, $query);
    $res=mysqli_fetch_assoc($res);
    file_get_contents($res);
```

The `$res` here is an array representing a row in your table, while the `file_get_contents` expect the parameter to be string.
I guess, the url that you are trying to get is a field of that row in the table and you should write `file_get_contents($res['fieldName'])` instead.